# Projecting into subobject when retrieving observable (typescript/angular)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have some example json coming from an API into an Angular service, a collection of objects like so:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "one"
  },
  "stats" : {
    "voteCount": 8
  }
}
```

The 'data' part is what I'd like to submit back in a reactive form in angular, so I'd really like my observable to be a collection of objects with just the id and title:

```
export class SimpleIssue {
  id: number;
  title: string; 
}
```

In my angular service I get the data like so:

```
getItems(): Observable<SimpleIssue[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'simpleissues/')
        .map((response: Response) => <SimpleIssue[]> response.json())
        .do(thedata => console.log('all: ' + JSON.stringify(thedata)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I would have thought if I'd changed response.json() to response.json().data that might work, or if I added another .map after that line something like:

.map(blah => blah.data)

But no luck.  Incidentally, if I bring this in as an 'any' type, I can put {{ myItem.data | json }} and get back exactly what I'd expect, as it's dealing with each collection object.

Can I get this working, or am I missing a fundamental concept of sending different viewmodels for each view, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested but this should works for your case:

```
getItems(): Observable<SimpleIssue[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'simpleissues/')
        .map((response: Response) => <any[]> response.json())
        .map((arr: any[]) => arr.map(i => i.data))
        .do(thedata => console.log('all: ' + JSON.stringify(thedata)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, wouldn't have thought that one up by myself.  Cheers!